# Is there a best way to ask the user for tenure?

Tags: input-fields, time, spinner

I have a form related to Loan emi calculator in my application where users are required to input the loan tenure in years and months. For now I have implemented two spinners each for year and month values but is there any better way to collect the tenure from user?

Here is my current implementation:

[image: 2 spinners]

Comment: what platform(s) are you targeting?

Answer (score 2):

It is very likely that your target audience has certain common durations of loan. You can present these choices as quick list [max 5-7], and allow adjustment afterwards.  If you don't yet know the common durations, record what users of your system input.

e.g.
**Duration of loan**

- 3 years
- 4 years
- 20 years
- 25 years
- other duration...  *[when this is selected then display the duration input controls]*

*note* that I'm deliberately using more lay-person friendly terminology *'duration'* rather than *'tenure'*

Comment: A: I think providing the fixed number of options may not work in this aspect as my client would not agree. Anyways, thanks for your input.

Comment: Sure. Just to clarify "Other Duration" would then provide for input. Idea is catch majority of users with common durations.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see it this way, 
The year might not have a maximum value. The value for month cannot be more than 12. If it crosses that, it would add up to the year.

Possibilities,

You can have a simple input field for the year and a select type for the month. This would restrict the user in entering proper information without writing code for validation. Of course, basic validation will be needed.
One issue I can think of with this is that, the inputs will not really be consistent in their design.

Now, if both were to be simple input fields! The code for validating scenarios where, if the month value goes beyond 12, the year is added by 1 and so on has to be written. For the input field you can provide placeholders saying something like *1-12* for months and do some live validations. This would be a consistent looking design

If both the year and the month fields have a specific range of values, then you can implement the design with a select field. This would be easier and simple.

In the design you have implemented, if the fields have a direct edit option.. i.e if the user can directly click and write the values, there is not much need for such controls. A direct value entered will be preferred rather than clicking several times on the caret icon to give a value.

I hope, if not the solution, I was able to help you with some thoughts

Comment: your thought is far more convincing and I will give a try to this logic.

Comment: Glad  I could help